# Hadoop writing to a new file from mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, reduce

I am trying to write a program that takes a huge data set and then run some queries on it using `mapreduce`. I have a code like this:

```
public static class MRMapper
   extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
String output2="hdfs://master:9000/user/xxxx/indexln.txt";
  FileSystem Phdfs =FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
 Path fname1=new Path(output2);
BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Phdfs.create(fname1,true)));
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();
    long max=0;

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String binln = Long.toBinaryString(0x8000000000000000L | key).substring(1);
    out2.write(binln+"\n");
    out2.flush();
    String line = value.toString();
    String [] ST = line.split(",");
                    long val=Math.abs(Long.parseLong(ST[2]));
                    if (max < val){
                                    max= val;
                    }
                    else{
                            word.set(line);
                            context.write(word, val);
                     }
 }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to build an `indexfile` in the mapper. which would be used to access specific areas of the input file by the mappers. The mappers read a part of the input file based on the index and then print the part read and the number of lines read to the output. I am using one mapper with 9 reducers.

- My question goes, is it possible to create/write to a file different from the output file in the map function and also, can a reducer read a file that is open in the mapper? If yes, Am i on the right path or totally wrong or maybe `mapreduce` is not the way for this?  I apologize if this question sounds too noob but I'm actually a noob in `hadoop`. Trying to learn. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your are using a single mapper? Because Hadoop creates a number of mappers very close to the number of input splits ([more details](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces)).

The concept of input split is very important as well: it means very big data files are splited into several chuncks, each chunck assigned to a mapper. Thus, unless you are totally sure only one mapper is being used, you wont be able to control which part of the file you are workin on, and you will not be able to control any kind of global index.

Being said that, by using a single mapper in MapReduce is the same than not using MapReduce at all :) Maybe the mistake is mine, and I'm assuming you have only one file to be analyzed, is that the case?

In the case you have several big data files the scenario changes, and it could make sense to create a single mapper for each file, but you will have to create your own `InputSplit` and override the `isSplitable` method by returning always `false`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i have one file of size 50GB. So the best option is to go without MapReduce?

Comment: Due to your needs, it seem the big data file cannot be splited. Thus, IMHO it has no sense to use MapReduce since you are going to force only one mapper, what in the end is the same than having a single "traditional" process. The power of MapReduce comes from spliting a problem into more smaller problems, whose process is distributed all along a cluster of machines.